# CreateInstance Causes Application Crash C#

Tags: c#, reflection, crash

I am facing a problem of application crash on `windows xp SP3` for the below line of code which load dll dynamically at run time.

```
      ObjFileCrawlerClass = (IFileCrawlerClass)Activator.CreateInstance(libType);
```

on adding logs i cloud find that above line results in crash, there is no exception thrown either.

Tested my application on 10 different machines till date but it fails for the above machine.
Also tried creating a new VM machine with same system configuration `(XP, SP3)` but unable to reproduce the issue at my end.

Could this be related to some permission/security issues on the machine?

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by crash, what happens?

Comment: i have a 3 layer architecture and i am calling my business logic into a windows service, to troubleshoot the issue instead of windows service i wrote a console application which calls the business access layer. running the code through Console shows a microsoft pop up of reporting error to Microsoft, while running through windows service gives error Event ID 7034(on viewing eventviewer) then i executed the cmd sc query service-name on cmd prompt gives WIN32_EXIT_CODE 1067 error

Comment: on further drilling i came across this exception EventType : clr20r3     P1 : cdt.testpoc.exe     P2 : 1.0.0.0     P3 : 521de64a
P4 : mscorlib     P5 : 2.0.0.0     P6 : 461eee3d     P7 : 1230     P8 : 25     
P9 : system.typeloadexception